# EF Core : conversion from string to Date or string to Guid on update

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core 6.0 and want to pass an object in and update the necessary properties of my entity. The issue I'm having is that some of the properties are of different types and throws an error on the conversion. I'm trying to avoid setting each property manually.  If I use Automapper to convert my update to my entity, then certain properties that are not included in my update become null.

```
_context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(update);
```

For example, my entity has the following:

```
public class SampleEntity
{
    [Required] public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required] public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required] public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateOnly? BirthDate { get; set; }
    [Required] public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [Required] public DateTime CreatedByDate { get; set; }
}
```

My update object looks like this, coming in as a protobuf (GRPC):

```
{
    "Id": "2ab8dc25-3755-48fb-87e5-f7791d1c0afc"
    "FirstName": "Garry",
    "LastName": "White",
    "BirthDate": "01/02/1978"  
}
```

Is there some way to add a known conversion type such as string->Guid or string->DateOnly

Comment: _"The issue I'm having is that some of the properties are of different types and throws an **error** on the conversion"_ ... and what is missing from your question?

Comment: You asked an EF Core question about mapping dates and GUIDs but there's no table schema or object that gets saved. As for the update JSON, if that's the actual JSON string from which the new object is constructed, it's simply wrong and will cause problems long before it reaches EF Core. There's a standard way to represent dates in JSON - ISO8601. What does `01/02` mean? January 2 or February 1?

Comment: The sample Entity is the schema and the update object is a protobuf which knows nothing of a Guid or UUID, only string.

Comment: EF Core doesn't deal with Protobuf, it works with C# objects. A C# class is *not* a table schema - is that date field stored in a `varchar(10)` or a `date` field? Besides if you had created the table from that class using migrations you wouldn't have any strings to convert. It looks like the real problem is deserializing the protobuf message, not EF Core. Unless the table uses text types instead of the proper types, which is a table design problem